# What's the deal with the various MySQL versions?

Tags: mysql, linux, open-source

I haven't been paying attention for a while, but I just checked and the latest release of MySQL is at 5.5.

I always use what the vendor of whatever OS I'm using provides, which has been 5.0 or 5.1 for the last couple years.

This page lists two community versions, 5.1 and 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/

There is documentation for 5.0, 5.1, 5.4, 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

So:

1. What happened to 5.2, and 5.3?
2. Why do all distros, even the newest Ubuntu which is not considered to be particularly conservative, only ship with 5.0 and 5.1?

Comment: Suggest close, or move to CW at least.

Comment: It's a fair question, but probably best on ServerFault

Comment: I certainly don't mind if an admin wants to move it to serverfault (although I won't be able to comment there).

Answer (score 2):

dev.mysql.com is the DEVELOPMENT stream - both the [community](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/) and [enterprise](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/server.html) listings are 5.1.

That's why there's no 5.2 or 5.3 - 5.5 hasn't been released (to public, anyways).  But version numbers are semantic - marketing will muck with them for sake of better presentation.

Comment: MySQL probably jumped to 5.5 and 6.0, for similar reasons to Firefox: increase features and major fixes justify a larger jump in version numbers. Cluster starts all the way at 7!

Comment: If 5.2 and 5.3 were skipped for marketing reasons, why wasn't 5.4 as well?

And 5.4 is some sort of arbitrary point in the development cycle… is it what 5.5 is based off of?

Or is 5.4 development. 5.5 release, and then 5.6 will be development. 5.7 release?

Comment: @maxwellb: I saw Confluence go from 3.1 to 3.2 for what amounted to shortcut keys to modal windows for their rich text editor :/

Comment: @John: Versioning is entirely arbitrary.  You hope they base off the previous versions, but it's not guaranteed - I've had to do parallel releases in the past :(

Answer (score 1):

5.1 is the latest GA version, others (5.4, 5.5, whatever other number they're using) are not considered ready for production use. Therefore the distros won't ship it, in particular because they might include features which subsequently get dropped, and your app might then depend on them (MySQL don't guarantee continued support of features not yet present in any GA version).

I would suggest always using Sun/Oracle binaries rather than Linux distribution ones, as they will not include dodgy vendor patches, which history suggests do not always improve software.

Comment: That is sad. Even Debian and Ubuntu have dodgy patches?

Comment: Debian have done so historically. I have no idea whether they still do. Ubuntu typically use the same packages as Debian.